# How to use wx.choicebox contents?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am new to python , doing small GUI project using wxpython,

Here is my code:
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib

class install(wx.Frame):

```
  def __init__ (self):

     wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Instal Deb', size=(250, 300), style = wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.SYSTEM_MENU)

     panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)


    text = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, label = 'System Name?', pos=(15,15))

    basicText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, " ",pos=(15,32), size=(100,-1))

    basicText.SetInsertionPoint (0)



  sampleList = [' ', 'abc','xyz']

  wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "system Type?" , pos=(15, 70))

  wx.Choice(panel, -1, (15, 85), choices=sampleList)


   wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Licence :", pos=(15,125))


      self.Center()
```

if **name** == '**main**':

```
app = wx.PySimpleApp()

 install().Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

I wanted to add 2 more choice box(ex: xx & yy)under the text "licence".when i select "Hybrid " in the system type choicebox both have to be appear or stay there as before but when i select "NVR" in the choicebox , "YY"  choicebox should disappear,
as i am new to this i am not able to understand how to do. please help me to sort my problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def OnChoice1(evt):
   print self.ch1.SelectedString()
   self.ch2 = wx.Choice(panel,-1,(x,y),choices=["ABC".split()]
def __init__(self):
...
   self.ch1 =  wx.Choice(panel, -1, (15, 85), choices=sampleList)
   self.ch1.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE,OnChoice1)
```

Ill let you fill in some of the blanks but thats most of what you need to know

Comment: I didnot understand properly..sorry:(

Comment: you need to assign the choice to a variable , then bind it to the choice event.  then in the choice event handler you can get the selected choice and display what you want accordingly

Comment: Error:self.ch1.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE,On_choice1), Name error: global name 'On_choice1'is not defined'

Comment: please help me to find exactly what is that error and hw it can be resolved

Comment: you need to have a On_choice1 method ... and probably attach it to the class and bind it to self.on_choice1